# Not able to use recursion in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, swift-playground

I am using this function

```
    func countFrom(from:Int, #to:Int) -> () {
        println("\(from)")
        if from < to {
             countFrom(from + 1, to: to)
        }
    }
    countFrom(1, to: 10)
}
```

But on compiling i get Swift Compiler Error -

Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1

And if i removed "countFrom(from + 1, to: to)", then there is no more error. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Should it be self.countFrom... ?

Comment: This is a known issue in Xcode 6 beta 4 -- nested functions that recurse crash the compiler. They mention it in the release notes and say the workaround is to "move recursive functions to the outer type or module context."

Comment: "Command /Applications/Xcode6-**Beta2**.app/Contents/..." Well, for starters, I'd upgrade to the latest beta before asking too many questions about weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: the code is fine, the compiler is outdated.  Per @Matt's comment, this works fine in Beta 4.

Console Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```